# How do I display line breaking markers while printing or displaying QTextDocument?

Tags: qt, line-breaks, word-wrap, qtextedit, qtextdocument

Imagine that I have very long lines in my text document. I want such lines to be broken to fit in width. But I also want such places to be marked in some way, for example:

[image]

Here, one short line is presented, then three lines are presented, each one is broken into two to fit in width, and each such break is marked with these markers (just Unicode symbols): ↲ ↳.

In this example I have monospaced font and thereby I was able to did the hack by simply inserting newlines and markers manually. I'm wondering is there a better way, which would use internal Qt's text layouting mechanisms and work with non-monospaced fonts? I do not really care about what kind of markers will be - it can be red line drawn after the text separately, I just need the information about line breaks done.

I do not care about rich texts much too, plain text is also good.

Comment: See how Creator does it? It might involve creating a custom `QTextLayout`.

Comment: There should be no problem with non-monospaced fonts. `QFontMetrics` is able to measure width of any given text.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I know about `QFontMetrics`, but monospaced fonts are not the problem - the fact that it will require me to typeset lines and set line breaks in this hacky way is the problem, Qt already does that and I all want is to re-use this.